# How can I run the InternetExplorerDriver through a linux VM?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, centos, selenium-webdriver

What are the options here as our plan is to be able to execute selenium tests on a linux (CentOS) vm using jenkins to schedule the execution using selenium and we only need to test Internet Explorer 9 at this time.

Has anyone had any luck using Wine with them?

What are my other options?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, consider this more like a guess than an answer:

- I would go by the path of investigating the [Selenium Grid](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) in setup that your main machine with CentOS would play "hub" role and virtual machine would be "node" - Everything you need to investigate is how to "see" the virtual machine by entering its IP. I think this should be somehow possible, but do not know how to setup it

Comment: I agree.  Since IE isn't avialble on linux/unix based systems, you'll need to use the "RemoteWebDriver" instead of InternetExplorerDriver.  There is always Wine or other virtual PC solutions out there if you want to keep it on the same box. You won't be able to see the browser interact but use a lot of console outs and you'll know exactly where things break if they do.  I'd suggest setting up the [node as a Windows Service](http://brantleytec.blogspot.com/2012/11/selenium-hub-and-node-as-windows-service.html) to make things easier on you.